# How to share a variable (not for modification) in python using multithread?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to parallelize a function I wrote for sequential program. Below is the input and output

Input 1, list of string : `["foo bar los angles", "foo bar new york", ...]`

Input 2, list of string as dictionary: `["los angles", "new york"..]`

I want to remove all string in input 2 from input 1. So the output will be like:

```
["foo bar", "foo bar"].
```

I'm able to do it using a double for loop.

```
res = []
for s1 in input1:
    for s2 in input2:
        if s2 in s1:
            res.append(s1.replace(s2, ""))
```

But this run a little slow (more than 10 minutes on my macbook pro) on 2 million size of list input1 (input 2 is couple of thousands).

I found a way to use python's `multithreading.dummy.Pool`. And use `pool.map` along with a global variable to parallelize it. But I'm concern about the usage of global variable. Is it safe to do so? Is there a better way to for python multithread to share a variable (May be like apache spark's `mapPartions`)?

I'm using Python 2.7 now. So I'd prefer answer use python2.

Comment: As an intermediary step before you go ahead with the parallelization, you could probably make your code a lot faster just by switching the lists to sets (if that's okay for your problem)

Comment: Do you need to preserve ordering of the original list?

Comment: @Tyler Well. I don't think use set will boost up performance. Because I still need to traverse the whole set. My requirement is remove substring in items of input1 if that substring is in input2. So I don't think use set will improve performance.

Comment: @rrauenza No, I don't need to preserve the ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally recommended to avoid multithreading when wanting performance because of the [GIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294382/what-is-a-global-interpreter-lock-gil).  Luckily we have [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import itertools
import multiprocessing

in1 = ["foo bar los angles", "foo bar new york",]
in2 = ["los angles", "new york",]

results = []

def sub(arg):
    s1, s2 = arg
    if s2 in s1:
        return s1.replace(s2, "")

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
for result in pool.imap(sub, itertools.product(in1, in2)):
    if result is not None:
        results.append(result)

print results
```

It sounds like your 2 million item list is already in memory, so you'll want to use `imap` not `map` in order to keep from turning the product into a thousands of millions item list.  I also use `itertools.product` to do the cartesian product of your inputs -- which is what your nested loop was doing.

Your requirements were a little vague in terms of uniqueness -- you were only adding to the results if you found a match.

Since we only add to `results` in the main body, there is no need to worry about the global `results` variable.  If you were using `multithreading` your `map` function could write directly to the results variable because of the GIL's protection ....but your concurrency would also be suffering from the GIL as well.

Note you can tune the `imap` by passing a large `chunksize`.  You can optimize further by relaxing the ordered requirement by using `imap_unordered`.  See [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you rrauenze. But just a follow up question, what if I want to add another input for function sub? Assume input1 is list of list [["foo bar los angles"],["foo bar new york"]], and I need to pass in a int variable 0 to access the inner list and get the string. Is there a way not using global variable to share it?

Comment: I don't understand thus question.  Can you revise your posted question to be more accurate regarding what you want to do?